# Windows Server 2012: trying to copy files via command line, getting permission denied

Tags: file-permissions, uac, windows-server-2012

This makes no sense to me. I'm logged in as `Administrator`, I run PowerShell as `Administrator`, and I even went to the Control Panel and moved the UAC slider thing all the way down. What the heck is going on here?

I'm trying to copy major folders from `C:` to `E:`, for the purpose of automatically backing these folders up. It seems to me, as `Administrator`, I should have full access like `root` does on Linux, especially for only reading files.

So, why am I getting access/permissions errors when trying to copy `C:\Users` or `'C:\Program Files'`?

Comment: Some files are not owned by administrator how stupid that ever sounds. It's not like Linux root unfortunately. I have had problems deleting some files on Windows even after changing the owner and permissions. It's just another Windows feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try resolve this by taking ownership of the particular folder, though you are a administrator user. Use the below command and try out the result.

On the command line, change to that particular directory and run the below command:

```
C:\important>takeown /F * /R
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: On a clean server build there's a *reason* the Administrator doesn't own certain files & folders, so think twice about running this command on anything but a test build.